# Site Navigation: Horizontal text-based menu with multiple tiers

Tags: php, html

Rather than have a typical Menu or Nav Bar, I'd like to know the best practice to accomplish the following:

**Breakfast | Lunch | Dinner**        <-- main site Menu, static always displayed (line1)

**Lunch1 | Lunch2 | Lunch 3**          <-- if Lunch selected above, show sub pages (line2)

**L1-Item1 | L1-Item2 | L1-Item3**    <-- If Lunch1 selected, show child pages (line3)

I'd like all these links to represent the folder hierarchy of my website.  Lines 2 & 3 above are dynamic content, in that they display nav links that correspond to their parent item.  The links on line3 will ultimately display page content.

It's like a breadcrumb menu, although it doesn't focus on where you've been (history) - but what is before you...

I'm not asking for any code, per se - as my main interest is in the best way to tackle this from a modular view-point.  As it is the navigation system, I'd rather not use client-scripting (javscript, jquery, etc.)

I'd like the content of this menu to be a dynamic representation of the site map, so when I add a page to the site, an item gets added or edited in the menu, etc.

Anyone know of any best patterns, practices, and/or examples where a nav system like this might exist?

Comment: Do you mean like a drop down menu like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/sVmPx/

Comment: Kev - no, I'm trying to break from the traditional drop-down menu.  It appears as static inline text, with lines 2 & 3 appearing based on what parent item was selected.

Comment: kind of like this http://www.peverel.co.uk/

Comment: Very much so.  I shall look through this, thanx.